# AUCTeX problem when splitting documents

Tags: auctex

I have a problem using AUCTeX style files when a document is broken into a main file and a preamble.
For instance, say my preamble is contained in the following file preamble.tex:

```
% --------- preamble.tex begins here -----------
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
% --------- preamble.tex ends here -----------
```

And my document document.tex is this one:

```
% --------- document.tex begins here -----------
\input{preamble.tex}
\begin{document}
  Lorem ipsum...
\end{document}
%%% Local Variables:
%%% mode: latex
%%% TeX-master: "preamble"
%%% End:
% --------- document.tex ends here -----------
```

The problem is that AUCTeX doesn't know that I am using `csquotes` and `tcolorbox` packages, and thus it doesn't load the corresponding style files. Note I have included the `TeX-master` instruction.

(Of course, if I join the two files in one, AUCTeX is aware of my packages and everything works just fine.)

How can I fix this?

Thanks.

Comment: I think I already answered you in the AUCTeX mailing list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Issue <kbd>C-u C-c C-n</kbd> (or from menu `LaTeX` → `Multifile/Parsing` → `Reset AUCTeX`) in `preamble.tex`'s and then in `document.tex`'s buffer, in this order.

Please note that the `TeX-master-file` variable is wrongly set.  It refers to the main file, the file you actually compile, which is `document.tex`.  In `document.tex` you should set to `t`, and in `preamble.tex` to `"document"`.